# Is it ok to dupe a question if a user can't get an existing answer to work?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

A user found an existing question which contained a solution that they were not able to get to work.

*To their credit, [they **did** ask for help in the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361531/how-can-i-programmatically-compose-a-message#comment60705124_34459852).*

However [they also reposted the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552533/watchkit-sms-with-preset-body) with the explanation that they needed help getting the original answer to work.

Isn't the appropriate action to offer a bounty on the original question to draw more attention to it, instead of duping it?

*I'm fairly sure the answer is "The question shouldn't be duped," but I haven't come across this situation before, and wanted to verify that I should be voting to close that second question as a dupe.*

Comment: The fact that a user can't get a solution to work doesn't invalidate a dupe. It might indicate information has been omitted by the new OP though as the solution SHOULD work... Right?

Comment: I'd say "How do I do X?" and "Why isn't this specific code to do X working?" are different questions.  Asking for help via a comment on the answer gets the attention of one user, who can edit their answer; asking for help with a new question gets the attention of everyone, not just the answerer, and they can provide full answers instead of just comments.  That said, if they just re-ask "How do I do X?", their question is probably missing important information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D Or, the OP of the first question omitted information. Or the solution is no longer valid (think broken APIs). Or the original OP marked it as accepted because their issue was solved via another solution and they wanted to close the question. Unless people can deduce that it *is* a duplicate, it should not be closed as one

Comment: I agree...if extra information is supplied then it is a new question and not a dupe....that was my point.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you have found the original question if the new one hadn't been posted?

Comment: @KyleStrand No, and I doubt anyone else would have either, unless a bounty was offered on the original question.

Comment: Here's the problem with reposting a question like that:  there are people who will continue to visit the old question that will not benefit from an answer posted on the new question.

Comment: @cimmanon I already posted [an answer to the old question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36567031/4151918) to handle the situation you described.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The question is not a duplicate.  The first question is "How do I do X?", while the second is "Why do I get this error message when trying this solution to X?"

It would be inappropriate to repost the same question, but the user didn't actually do that: they wrote a new, different question that references the original.

Comment: I think the key point in this answer is: "they wrote a new, different question that **references the original**." Not only to separate it from the OP, but to follow a path for any other user that is trying to achieve the same thing. This will prevent others from creating dupes.

Comment: This isn't a terrible answer as, speaking abstractly, you are correct. But wouldn't it have been better if the OP had simply commented on the original answer and _not accepted it_ until the answer were fixed so that it solved the problem? A database of questions about how to make answers in the same database work doesn't seem monumentally useful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The original question was asked by a different user. I don't know how to check this, but I wouldn't be surprised if the answer had already been accepted by the time the new user (i.e. the one asking the new question) found the old question and posted their comment.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Oh, right. Well I guess it could go either way then. If the new OP's just being silly then it's not worth a new question, but perhaps there's some fundamental aspect of the new OP's specific environment that changes something about the answer, and that might be worthwhile. Hopefully the usual quality reqs will sort between the two. I do think that it would be best not to rely on "how do I fix the code I saw in <this answer>" and re-present it as a fresh problem that can be searched for etc without knowledge of the original question. Again, MCVE requirement probably gets us there.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As far as I can tell, it looks kind of like the problem in this case wasn't specific to new OP's environment, but there was no way for new OP to know that when they posted their question. So in this case they probably would have been okay waiting for an answer to their comment, but I don't know if PetahChristian would have seen the old question if they hadn't posted the new one.

Comment: It's a tricky grey area as a question-asker, I think; in fact, one of my [top-voted SU questions](http://superuser.com/q/876912/199803) started out as a similar "I can't get this other answer to work" question.

Comment: @Kyle Mmmm yeah I think you've convinced me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't think the old OP recognized the issue with their self-answer, so the new user would have been waiting a long time for an answer to their comment until a (bounty was offered or) new question was asked, to draw other eyes to the issue.